# Как добавлять новую строку лога в начало файла (rsyslog)

Tags: bash, rsyslog

Есть файл `/etc/rsyslog.d/file.conf`

В файле написано `:msg,contains,"text" /var/log/file.log`

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли задать в этом файле добавление новой строки лога в начало файла лога, а не в конец? Сейчас я пользуюсь `:$ tac /var/log/file.log | less` чтобы последние строки лога оказались наверху, а хотелось бы просто пользоваться nano, например.

Comment: Добавление строки в начало означает полную перезапись всего файла. Оно вот реально надо?

Comment: То есть, каждый раз при добавлении строки нужно перезаписывать файл? Такой ценой конечно нет. Но, например, в python случалось решать задачу, чтобы новая строка добавлялась в начало файла. Я подумал вдруг rsyslog так тоже умеет. Но в мануалах поиск пока не навёл.

Comment: *в python случалось решать задачу, чтобы новая строка добавлялась в начало файла.* Если от Вас скрыли полную перезапись, это не означает, что её не было.

Comment: ок, тогда что вы называете полной перезаписью файла? Если я открою файл в nano и добавлю в начало новую строку, файл перезапишется? А если добавлю новую строку в конец файла, то нет? Или когда rsyslogd добавляет новую строку в конец файла, он делает это как-то иначе чем nano.

Comment: *Если я открою файл в nano и добавлю в начало новую строку, файл перезапишется?* Да, весь. Альтернативно - удалится и создастся новый, что один хрен. *А если добавлю новую строку в конец файла, то нет?* Будут перезаписаны только концевые секторы (или кластеры), содержащие изменённые данные, ну и плюс новые, если будут добавлены. *Или когда rsyslogd добавляет новую строку в конец файла, он делает это как-то иначе чем nano.* Ни одна программа вообще этим не занимается. Она просто даёт задание операционной системе, а та делает. так что неважно, какая именно программа - всегда одинаково.

Comment: Понятно, благодарю вас. Это для меня новое интересное открытие. И, в таком случае, ничего страшного в данной ситуации в перезаписи не вижу, там файл от силы мегабайт.

Comment: Отдельно непонятно зачем нужен nano для просмотра лога